# What would cause CI to falsely return null values?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm running this in CI, and `$query->result_array()` is returning null values, however, when I use $this->db->last_query(), and print out the query, then run it in a MySQL client (Sequel Pro), I get values back as I would expect. What would cause this to return NULL when doing it through CI? I've got other queries that look very similar and work just fine, but this one's being fussy.

Here is the code for the query:

```
public function get_current_eval($pers_id = NULL, $assID = NULL){
$query = $this->db->select('person.last_name, person.rest_of_name, person.id')
    ->from('person_course_conceptual_assessment AS pcca')
    ->join('person', 'person.id = pcca.faculty_id')
    ->where('pcca.assessment_id', $assID)
    ->get()
    ->result_array();        
  return $query;
}
```

This is what it's returning

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [last_name] =>
        [rest_of_name] =>
        [id] => 000000000
    )
)
```

Here's what $this->db->last_query() returns:

```
SELECT person.last_name, person.rest_of_name, person.id
FROM (person_course_conceptual_assessment AS pcca)
JOIN person ON person.id = pcca.faculty_id
WHERE `pcca`.`assessment_id` =  '123456'
```

I copied that straight to the MySQL GUI and pasted it just as a normal query, runs fine, and returns correct values for all 3 params. Any ideas as to what would cause this for this specific instance?

Comment: Lose the parentheses. Just cuz one works doesn't mean another driver won't fail

Comment: the semicolon was an error copying into the question here. It's not in the code. Fixed above.  Which parentheses are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some thing like

Check can get $variables like $assID

```
public function get_current_eval($pers_id, $assID){
    $this->db->select('p.last_name, p.rest_of_name, p.id');
    $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix .'person_course_conceptual_assessment pcca', 'left');
    $this->db->join($this->db->dbprefix . 'person p', 'p.id = pcca.id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('pcca.assessment_id', $assID);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It returns a single row, but all empty values just as my code did.

Comment: What does this return $assID

Comment: If I echo the parameters, they're both valid. But the values returned in the result array are all empty including `$assID`.

Comment: Try with out where() just for testing

Comment: The other option is return $query->row_array();

Comment: If I pull out the where clause I'm getting valid and empty arrays, and `row_array()` just returned the first entry, which happens to be valid, but that's for the whole table.

Comment: It turns out it's an issue with the table, modifying of such is above my pay grade, so I'll bug someone about it tomorrow. I appreciate your help!